# Add classname when click on a button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This is my code when I click on a button i want it add a className but this code only work on desktop but not in mobile device

```
const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
setPageEventNumber(selected);

const eventContainerWrapper = document.getElementById("eventContainerWrapper");
eventContainerWrapper.className += " page-enter";
setTimeout(() => {
  eventContainerWrapper.className = eventContainerWrapper.className.replace(" page-enter", "");
}, 2000);
```

};`

This is the screenshot of inspect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0w52.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue you are experiencing is related to the fact that mobile devices are touch-based, while desktops use a mouse to interact with the UI. In your current code, the class is added when the button is clicked, which is triggered by a mouse click event. However, on mobile devices, the button may be triggered by a touch event instead. try this code instead, hope it work.

```
const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
      setPageEventNumber(selected);
    
      const eventContainerWrapper = document.getElementById("eventContainerWrapper");
      eventContainerWrapper.className += " page-enter";
      setTimeout(() => {
        eventContainerWrapper.className = eventContainerWrapper.className.replace(" page-enter", "");
      }, 2000);
    };
    
    // Assuming you have a button component like this:
    const Button = ({ onClick }) => {
      return (
        <button onClick={onClick} onTouchStart={onClick}>
          Click me
        </button>
      );
    };
    
    // Usage:
    <Button onClick={changePage} />
```